# How to ensure AEM 6.4 code will be compatible with AEM 6.5

Tags: aem

We are planning to migrate AEM version from 6.4 to 6.5. How do we ensure the current codebase(built on AEM 6.4) will be compatible with AEM 6.5?

Will pattern detector help here ? Do we have any other way to identify if AEM 6.4 code will be compatible with AEM 6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the 6.4 AEM codebase inherited from a previous version (6.3 or older)? If the current site was developed with 6.4, more likely your site should work, but the only way is to test.

You have to take into account if you want to preserve all the content versioning (at the AEM level) or if a single package with the pages, XF, tags, and assets is enough.

Other than that, upgrade the AEM UberJar version and make a clean install and review the AEM logs. Make sure all the Java bundles are active, etc.

It is also helpful to capture visual evidence of the current look and feel and compare against the same pages running in 6.5.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern detector is the first step, yes. The only way to truly ensure that the codebase is compatible is testing.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be absolutely sure is to build your project using the AEM 6.5 archetype.

The pattern detector will help identify potential issues but it won't guarantee that the code will be compatible.